# Set focus to newly added row in ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using ui-grid. The use-case is such that on clicking a button, a new row is added. I want to set focus on the first cell of the newly added row Any suggestions on how to do it ? Here's a [`plunkr`](http://plnkr.co/edit/6zyZ5q) for the same.
http://plnkr.co/edit/6zyZ5q

```
$scope.addNew = function() {
var newobj = {"id": "","name":"" }; 
$scope.gridOptions.data.unshift(newobj);
$scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ROW); 

//set focus to the new row 
$scope.gridApi.cellNav.scrollToFocus( $scope.gridOptions.data[0], $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[0]);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.gridApi.cellNav.scrollToFocus(
    $scope.termGridOptions.data[0],
    $scope.termGridOptions.columnDefs[0]
 );
});
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I tried the following but still nothing happens.
'    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.gridApi.cellNav.scrollToFocus($scope.gridOptions.data[0], $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[0]);
    },3000);'

Comment: turns out, ui-grid requires some time delay to update the data. so a small delay, (achieved using $interval) did the trick.